# Как подключиться к wi-fi точке доступа использующей не стандартный канал

Tags: linux, debian, wifi

Имеется открытая точка доступа в диапазоне 2.4 Ггц, но она имеет не стандартный канал (35-й) и не видна в списке доступных сетей для подключения, ее видит только airodump-ng. Я выяснил что 35-й канал имеет центральную частоту 2434 MHz.
Подскажите, как подключиться к ней в дебиан 9 или хотябы в какую сторону копать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: поиграйся с regdomain. https://hackware.ru/?p=4125

Answer (score 2):

В файле /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

```
    network={
       ssid="btk24-4"
       key_mgmt=NONE
    }
```

Или через комманду wpa_passphrase создаешь этот файл конфигурации.
Далее через свой интерфейс коннектишься

```
wpa_supplicant -B -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Или через wpa_cli, там много чего еще можно посмотреть

```
wpa_cli
>scan
>scan_results
>add_network
35
>set_network 35 ssid "btk24-4"
>set_network 35 psk ""
>enable_network 35
```

Но это очень странно, что 35 канал висит на 2,4GHz. 14 каналов должно быть на частоте 2.4GHz. Скорее всего эта точка лежит в диапазоне 5GHz. Вот и копай туда.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но к сожалению ни один из способов не помог. 
Карточка умеет только 2.4
Точка доступа ubiquiti

Comment: Для того чтоб туда подключиться - нужно поправить скан-лист